# Excel custom function from Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

in VBA we can create a function that we can then call directly and with arguments from excel sheet .
I'm wondering if there is same possibility with power query instead of VBA.
Note, I know you can create user defined functions within power query, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a Power Query function outside of the query editor, at least not directly in an Excel formula. You can set a table of inputs and run it through a query to get a table of outputs but that requires refreshing the query every time you change the inputs.